# Use only two functions from the evil package as keybinding

Tags: emacs, evil-mode

I want to get the [search at point functionality](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SearchAtPoint) ("*" and "#") in emacs.

So I want to use "*" and "#" from the [emacs evil-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Evil), as this is one of the suggestions. However, I don't want anything else from the evil-mode, just those two functions!

This is my `.emacs` file:

```
(package-initialize)
(evil-mode 1)        ;; enable evil-mode
(global-set-key (kbd "C-*") 'evil-search-symbol-forward)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-#") 'evil-search-symbol-backward)
```

Now the keybindings work, but I loaded the whole `evil-mode`, so it messes up my standard emacs keybindings like "C-y" for yank.

If I don't load the `evil-mode` in the `.emacs` file, I get the error:

```
Symbol's function definition is void: evil-search-symbol-forward
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@event_jr's answer mentions `highlight-symbols`, which is probably a much more lightweight way to do what you want.

However, if you really want to use the `evil` version, you can `(require 'evil)` in your `.emacs` file *without* turning it on (ie, leave off the `(evil-mode 1)` statement).

Meanwhile, the functions you want are actually named `evil-search-word-forward` and `evil-search-word-backward`, not the `...-symbol-...` version you saw on the wiki page (which is probably outdated).

Answer (score 1):

You should use [highlight-symbols](https://github.com/nschum/highlight-symbol.el/blob/master/highlight-symbol.el) for symbol jumping and highlighting.